# What are the minimal set of privileges required to use the rest Search API with Nexus 3?

Tags: nexus, nexus3

I'm using Nexus Repository Manager OSS 3.13-0.0.1 and I'm trying to find the minimal privileges to use the Search API.

In the documentation the `admin` account is used : [Search API Documentation](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/search-api)

I've tried the `nx-search-read` privilege but is always return an empty result (this is not the case with the admin account).

Do I have to add more privileges in order to be able to use the Search API ?

Answer (score 1):

The only other thing that should be needed is to grant read permissions to the components they should be able to search.  E.g. nx-repository-view-maven2-*-read